How to display a prompt for user input in PL/SQL on Oracle 10g?
I am writing a code in PL/SQL on Oracle 10g which requires a user input. I want to give a prompt for user input which I can't to do so. It'd be great if you help!
I tried the following code, just to test if the prompt was working or not. However, the code if giving an error as "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement". Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong?
ACCEPT x NUMBER PROMPT 'Please enter a value';
DECLARE
  a NUMBER:=&x;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(a);
END;
/


What client application are you using to talk to the database?

@MT0 I used the SQL command interface of the Oracle 10g application express

PL/SQL does not allow user input.

ACCEPT is an SQL*Plus command that is run on the client and takes user input and stores it in a substitution variable. It runs on the client and does NOT run on the database.
&x is a substitution variable and SQL*Plus (and other clients that support substitution variables) will take the value of the substitution variable and effectively do a find-replace substituting the variable for its value. Then the replaced text is sent to the database (which never sees the original text). Again, the database does NOT understand substitution variables.
So, if you are running your code via a client application that supports substitution variables (SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, SQLCl and some others) then your code will be parsed by the client, substituted and sent to the database.
If you are running on a different client (that does not support substitution variables) then your code is invalid because ACCEPT is not a PL/SQL command (and PL/SQL does not support taking user input) and the client will send the code to the database as-is and the database will not understand it.

Thanks a lot! However, can you please tell me a way as to how to write a prompt on PL/SQL?

@Rose You cannot as the PL/SQL language does not support it (PL/SQL and SQL are both run on the database server and do not dynamically take user input from clients). If you are using a client application that supports providing user input before sending a statement to the database then you need to use the appropriate syntax for that client but you haven't told us what client application you are using.

I'm not sure why you got that error, because code you posted works OK in SQL*Plus (command line tool), as well as e.g. SQL Developer (a GUI tool).
Here's a demo; SQL*Plus first:
SQL> accept x number prompt 'Please enter a value ';
Please enter a value 123
SQL>
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    a number := &x;
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line(a);
  5  end;
  6  /
old   2:   a number := &x;
new   2:   a number :=        123;
123

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>


SQL Developer:
ACCEPT opens a pop-up window which asks for a value:

I entered a value, then executed anonymous PL/SQL block:

As you can see, it works.

With "it works", I meant to say that there's no error you posted. What did you do to cause it?
Apart from that, read what MT0 said in their answer.

Hi, so, I used the SQL command interface in the Oracle 10g application express. That is the main reason why I was getting an error. If I had been using a different client application, then I perhaps would have had the same results as you did.
